# How to ensure vuetify's dropdown menu has the highest z-index?

Tags: vuetify.js, apexcharts

I'm using a `v-combobox` component that spans over the whole width of the grid.

Right below it, there's a chart (ApexCharts) with some toolbar icons and these icons seem to have higher `z-index` than expanded dropdown list of the combobox:

[image: Toolbar icons put over dropdown menu options]

Is there any way to increase the `z-index` of dropdown menu to make it appear on top of these icons? ApexCharts seem not to have any option like this to be configured through settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's enough to add the `z-index` value to the `v-combobox` definition as a plain style:

```xml
<v-combobox
   v-model="selectedItem"
   label="Type or select item name"
   :items="availableItems"
   @change="updateDescription"
   clearable
   style="z-index: 12"
></v-combobox>
```

`ApexCharts` positions the toolbox icons with `z-index` equal to 11 (found out in dev. console), so setting up 12 is enough to cover the icons with expanded dropdown menu.